# Delete spaces, hyphens, and underscores in filenames?

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

What is a good command to delete spaces, hyphens, and underscores from all files in a directory, or selected files?

I use the following command with Thunar Custom Actions to slugify filenames:

```
for file in %N; do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | tr -s ' ' | tr ' A-Z' '-a-z' | tr -s '-' | tr -c '[:alnum:][:cntrl:].' '-')"; done
```

But that command only replaces spaces with dashes/hyphens and lowercases capped characters.

I've used the following command in terminal to delete spaces from thousands of filenames in a folder, and it worked pretty fast:

```
 rename "s/ //g" *
```

Again, it only deletes spaces, and not hyphens/dashes and underscores as well.

Ideally I don't want any spaces, hyphens/dashes, and underscores in my filenames. And it would be great if the command could be used with Thunar Custom Actions on selected files.

Comment: I note one problem that a lot of the proposed solutions have, is not properly checking the existance of the "new" name before mv'ing the file.  Not doing that could be the potential source of a lot of problems.

Comment: Is it possible to modify John1024's command to check for that?

Comment: @user8547 `rename -i "s/[-_ ]//g" *`

Comment: Thank you Sparhawk. Incidentally, for those interested in using this as a Thunar Custom Action, the command for Thunar is: for file in %N; do mv "$file" `echo $file | sed -e 's/[ _-]//g'`; done

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The version of `rename` that comes with the `perl` package supports regular expressions:

```
rename "s/[-_ ]//g" *
```

Alternatively,

```
rename -i "s/[-_ ]//g" *
```

The `-i` flag will make `rename` use interactive mode, prompting if the target already exists, instead of silently overwriting.

Perl's rename is sometimes called `prename`.

#### Perl's rename versus util-linux's rename

On Debian-like systems, perl's rename seems to be the default and the above commands should just work.

On some distributions, the `rename` utility from util-linux is the default.  This utility is completely incompatible with Perl's `rename`.

- **All:** First, check to see if Perl's `rename` is available under the name `prename`.
- **Debian:** Perl's rename should be the default.  It is also available as `prename`.  The `rename` executable, though, is under the control of `/etc/alternatives` and thus could have been altered to something different.
- **archlinux:** Run `pacman -S perl-rename` and the command is available as `perl-rename`.  For a more convenient name, create an alias. (Hat tip: ChiseledAbs)
- **Mac OSX** According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/152627/renaming-many-files-in-mac-os-x-batch-processing), `rename` can be installed on OSX using homebrew via:

  ```
  brew install rename
  ```
- **Direct Download:**  `rename` is also available from Perl Monks:

  ```
   wget 'http://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=displaycode;node_id=303814' -O rename
  ```

Comment: I think that depends on what `rename` are you talking about. The one from **util-linux**-2.24.2-1.fc20.x86_64 does not support regular expressions.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I just checked the man page for the version of rename that you found.  Based on the arguments, the version of `rename` that the OP was using looks like the `perl` version and not the `util-linux` version.

Comment: For the record, this is the [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) man page for the **util-linux** version. Anyway, besides that note, the important thing is that the OP got his answer (and you an upvote from me :-D).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Thanks for finding that.  Back at you with a +1.

Comment: how to use or activate the perl version of rename when I have the util-linux version

Comment: @ChiseledAbs What OS and version or distribution are you using?

Comment: @John1024 archlinux, but i found out how, just go `pacman -S perl-rename` then I guess you can alias.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs Very good.  In case it might help others, I just added that info to the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I would replace all those `tr` commands, with a `sed` substitution command, e.g.:

```
for file in %N; do 
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed 's/[ _-]//g')"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Not counting `mv`, you don't really need an outside process for this at all - you can kind of just *poof* them.

```
ifsqz() ( LC_ALL=C sqz=$1
    isf() { [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ] ; }  
    set -- * ; set -f
    for f do isf "$f" || break
    IFS=$sqz; set -- $f; IFS=
    isf "$*" || mv -- "$f" "$*"
    done
)
```

Still though, that means a `mv` invocation per file, and so probably `rename` is better. Though this should work given only a POSIX `mv` in `$PATH` and a POSIX shell.

So, I came up with a kind of crazy demo for this. The test set is generated like:

```
tee - - - - <<CGEN |\
dd cbs=90 conv=unblock |\
sed 'G;$!N'";s/^/touch -- '/;s/$/'/" |sh
$( #BEGIN CGEN
   LC_ALL=C
   i= n='"$((i=((i=i+1)==10||i==39||i==47)>0?(i+1):i))"'
   printf '%b -_   ---___'  $(
   IFS=0; eval \
       printf '"\\\\%04o\\\\%04o "' "$(
       printf "$n"' "$i" '%s $(
       printf %.252d
#END
))"))
CGEN
```

In the first place I will be the first to acknowledge that the above command produces results that can be more easily obtained by other means. But other means would likely not demonstrate as well what might be done with `$IFS` and a little *(sick?)* imagination.

So the first bit is fairly straight-forward:

- `tee` pipes out 5 copies of its input - the heredocument called `CGEN`
- `dd` blocks its input by newlines at 90 bytes per block and pipes that to ...
- `sed` joins 2 of those blocks on two `\n`ewline characters, `'`single-quotes the results, and prepends the string `touch --` for every line cycle before piping out to ...
- `sh` which then executes all input as shell commands

The `#CGEN` bit though... Well, briefly...

- the bottom `printf` prints 252 0s
- the next from last receives 252 `''` null-string arguments and for each prints the contents of `$n` followed by the string `" $i "`
- `eval` interprets the arguments of the next up `printf` before it prints the results of that interpretation as octal nums prepended by 2 backslashes a piece
- the last `printf` prints the byte values for those octals 2 at a time followed by the string `-_   ---___` for each pair
- `$n` is initialized to an equation that will increment `$i` by one for every evaluation excepting that it skips the values 10, 39, or 47 - *(which are `\n`ewline, `'`single-quote, and `/`slash in ASCII decimal respectively)*

The end result is a directory containing a lot of really ugly filenames containing every  byte in my charset from 1 through 255 excepting the single-quote *(only skipped to avoid one more `sed s///` statement)* and the `/`slash. Those filenames look like this:

```
(set -- *; printf '%s\n\n##############\n\n%s\n' "${9}" "${34}")  | cat -A

   ---___ww -_   ---___xx -_   ---___yy -_   ---___zz -_   ---___{{ -_   ---___|| -_   ---$
$
___}} -_   ---___~~ -_   ---___^?^? -_   ---___M-^@M-^@ -_   ---___M-^AM-^A -_   ---___M-^BM-^B -_   ---___M-^CM-^C$
$
##############$
$
 -_   ---___M-ZM-Z -_   ---___M-[M-[ -_   ---___M-\M-\ -_   ---___M-]M-] -_   ---___M-^M-^ -_   ---___M-_M-_ -_$
$
---___M-`M-` -_   ---___M-aM-a -_   ---___M-bM-b -_   ---___M-cM-c -_   ---___M-dM-d -_   ---___M-eM-e -_   ---___$
```

Now I'll get some data on these files:

```
chksqz() ( LC_ALL=C sqz=$1
    set -- * ; set -f ; IFS= ; tc="$*"
    printf '#%s\n' \
        "There are $# files in this test directory." \
        "All filenames combined contain a total of ${#tc} bytes."
    IFS=$sqz ; set -- $* ; IFS= ; sc="$*"  
    printf "%s '$sqz'" \
        "#Of which ${#sc} bytes are not"\
        " and $((${#tc}-${#sc})) bytes are"
    set +f ; unset IFS
    printf ".\n#%s\n#Total:\t%d\n#Other:\t%d\n#'$sqz':\t%d\n" \
        "And to confirm these figures:" \
        $(  printf %s * | wc -c 
            printf %s * | tr -d "$sqz" | wc -c
            printf %s * | tr -dc "$sqz" | wc -c
))
chksqz '_ -'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
#There are 101 files in this test directory.
#All filenames combined contain a total of 17744 bytes.
#Of which 2692 bytes are not '_ -' and 15052 bytes are '_ -'.
#And to confirm these figures:
#Total: 17744
#Other: 2692
#'_ -': 15052
```

Ok. Now finally, to action:

```
ifsqz '_ -'
chksqz '_ -'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
#There are 101 files in this test directory.
#All filenames combined contain a total of 2692 bytes.
#Of which 2692 bytes are not '_ -' and 0 bytes are '_ -'.
#And to confirm these figures:
#Total: 2692
#Other: 2692
#'_ -': 0
```

Success! You can see for yourself:

```
ls

????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????
???????????????????????????
???????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????
??????????????????????
????????????????????????
??????????????????????????
??????????????????????????
??????????????????????????
??????????????????????????
???????????????????????????
???????????????????????????
???????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
??????????????????????????
????????????????????????
????????????????????
??????????????????
????????????????????????????
??
????????????????????????????
??????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????
????????????????????!!""##
??????????????????!!""##$$
????????????????!!""##$$%%
????????????!!""##$$%%&&((
????????!!""??##$$%%&&(())
$$%%&&(())**??++,,..0011
%%&&(())**++??,,..00112233
&&(())**++,,??..0011223344
))**++,,..??0011223344556
**++,,..00??11223344556677
22334455667788??99::;;<<==>>
445566778899??::;;<<==>>??@@
5566778899::;;??<<==>>??@@AA
6778899::;;<<??==>>??@@AABB
8899::;;<<==??>>??@@AABBCCDD
\\]]^^``aa??bbccddeeffgghh
]]^^``aabbc??cddeeffgghhii
^^``aabbccdd??eeffgghhiijj
??@@AABBCCDDEE??FFGGHHIIJJKK
AABBCCDDEEFF??GGHHIIJJKKLLM
BBCCDDEEFFGG??HHIIJJKKLLMMNN
CCDDEEFFGGHHII??JJKKLLMMNNOO
EEFFGGHHIIJJ??KKLLMMNNOOPPQQ
ffgghhiijjkk??llmmnnooppqqrr
gghhiijjkkllmm??nnooppqqrrss
iijjkkllmmnn??ooppqqrrsstt
jjkkllmmnnoo??ppqqrrssttuuvv
kkllmmnnooppqq??rrssttuuvvww
LLMMNNOOPPQQRR??SSTTUUVVWWXX
MNNOOPPQQRRSS??TTUUVVWWXXYY
OOPPQQRRSSTT??UUVVWWXXYYZZ[[
PPQQRRSSTTUUVV??WWXXYYZZ[[\\
RRSSTTUUVVWW??XXYYZZ[[\\]]
ssttuuvvwwxx??yyzz{{||}}~~??
ttuuvvwwxxyyz??z{{||}}~~????
uuvvwwxxyyzz{{??||}}~~??????
wwxxyyzz{{||??}}~~??????????
xxyyzz{{||}}~~??????????????
YYZZ[[\\]]^^??``aabbccddee
ZZ[[\\]]^^``??aabbccddeeff
```

Comment: +1 for a creative use of `IFS` + `printf`

Comment: @John1024 - what's really fun: `set -- 'some   arbitrary' args; eval printf '"%s\n"' "$(IFS=0; printf ' "$@" %s' $(printf %025d))"`

Comment: Is mikeserv's command supposed to be pasted into the terminal as one line? Or is it supposed to be made into a bash script?

Comment: @user8547 - if you want it one line, just replace the `\n`ewline chars with `;`semicolons. Else do `sh <<\CMD CTRL+V CTRL+J` then paste then `CTRL+V CTRL+J` and `CMD` and then enter. Or do `sh -c '` then paste then `'` and enter. There are a dozen ways, probably.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the command as one line? I just tried it on a few sample images and it deleted some characters that aren't hyphens, spaces, and underscores.

Comment: @user8547 - that's troubling. What shell are you using? I don't understand what the `%N` thing is, honestly. I'll expand on the answer in a moment. That's not a glob I commonly see.

Comment: `new="$(IFS=" -_"; printf %s $1)"` forks a subshell (except in ksh93) and has issues with tailing newlines. Another option is to use `IFS=' -_'; set -- $1; IFS=; new="$*"` (and change your while loop to a for loop)

Comment: You may want to add a `|| [ -L "$file" ]` to your `[ -e "$file" ]`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I did not consider the trailing newlines here - thank you. Still, rather than rework it I just went old-school on it. The subshell would normally be enough of an argument for me to rework it, but in this case the `mv` per file fairly nullifies, I think, any performance benefit it may have. The link thing though - could you go over that again for me, please? I'm missing something there, or in my understanding of the `-e`xist `test`...

Comment: `[ -e x ]` will return false if `x` is a symlink to an non-existing or non-accessible file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks yet again. That is an edge-case I will attempt to remember.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - yeah, squeezing on `$*` is cleaner. I was just too lazy before.

Comment: Nice shell Kung-Fu!

Answer (score 2):

if you have perl, you usually have rename. you can do:

```
> type rename
rename is /usr/bin/rename
```

and show how this script is written:

```
> cat /usr/bin/rename | head -n 5 #firt 5 lines for example
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
#  This script was developed by Robin Barker (Robin.Barker@npl.co.uk),
#  from Larry Wall's original script eg/rename from the perl source.
#
```

This script doesn't support -i flag (this is version in my system), but maybe yours supports.
What about arguments. First is regular expressions with PCRE format, it works like filter, modify input name to output name. List of input names you give by asterisk '*'.
for example, you do:

```
> cd /tmp
> rename 's/ //g' *
```

in real '*' can be expanded to:

```
> rename 's/ //g' file1 file2 file3 othe files found in current directory
```

When you have really big count files, you are in trap. shell will expand your line longer than system accepts. then you can do workaround using find or xargs. using 'find' is problem, because rename will be called many times equal to files count in directory. better use xargs with -r option. one rename call modify many files. for example:

```
> ls | xargs -r rename 's/ //g'   #thats all, names will be appended at the end of this command.
```

last problem, what does it mean:

```
's/ //g'
```

this is regular expression for modify names.
after first '/' is space. this is detected, and replaced by string after second '/'. But there is empty string ended with third '/', then space is replaced by nothing. Option 'g' makes this expression repetative. expression will walk for all name from begin to the end, and detects all spaces.

But what if you have tab character or other 'white' character? there is replacement for this '\s'. what other unneeded characters? simply add it to expression. All close with brackets, for example:

```
's/[\s_-]//g'
```

this is all. do you see similarity? I think you should read man perlrequick  and  man perlretut , this explain you (I hope) how regular expression works.
you can use rename command in your own script if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

The following `sh` shell loop will remove all spaces,  underscores and dashes from the names of files in the current directory, taking care to not overwrite any existing files:

```
for f in *; do
    test -f "$f" || continue
    nf=$( echo "$f" | tr -d ' _-' )
    ! test -e "$nf" && echo mv "$f" "$nf"
done
```

For `bash` and `ksh`, and being slightly more verbose with the logic:

```
for f in *; do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
        nf=$( tr -d ' _-' <<<"$f" )
        if [[ ! -e "$nf" ]]; then
            echo mv "$f" "$nf"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` when you're certain it does what you want it to do.

The `tr` command will delete (`-d`) any character in the given set of characters (`' _-'`).  It's important to have the dash in the very start or end of the set, or it will be interpreted as a range of characters.