# How to reformat sequence numbers in a batch of filenames, e.g. A1.txt to A0001.txt?

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx, rename

I have some files named as A1.txt A2.txt ... A11.txt A12.txt, etc. I want to rename them to A0001.txt A0002.txt ... A0011.txt etc. Am I doing it right?

```
for file in A*.txt
do
mv ${file} ${file/-#.txt-/-"%5d".txt}
done
```

Comment: Quite logical. Unfortunately, no shell I know can interpret sprintf(3) patterns like `"%5d"`. However, if you have GNU utilities on your system (which you probably do unless you are using BSD), check out `man 1 printf` or `info -f coreutils printf`. That might do what you want. Alternately, try @John1024's idea.

Comment: Since the OP explained in a comment to an answer that he/she is using a Mac, the answers in the possible duplicate may not be relevant. I haven't used a Mac in years so I'm not sure. In any case, I edited the question to include the `osx` tag.

Comment: @don_crissti You're right. I see that Gilles' answer actually had 4 solutions (including two that would work with Bash).

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have the `prename` option suggested by @John1024, you should be able to use the `printf` (a built-in in `bash`, but also available from GUN `coreutils`) to format the decimal digits with the desired field width and padding - unfortunately I don't think there's a one-step shell expansion to extract the digits, the closest I can get is

```
for file in A*.txt
do
  base="${file%.*}"
  printf -v newfile "A%04d.txt" "${base#A}"
  mv -- "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: I believe this is the best one can get with shell: +1.  (The script could be made POSIX, if anyone so desired, by replacing fourth line with `newfile=$(printf "A%04d.txt" "${base#A}")`)

Comment: @John1024 thanks for clarifying the POSIX option - I wasn't sure about that

Comment: Is `base` a keyword? Would you please explain what each line do?

Comment: @Christin `base` is just an arbitrary variable name - used to hold the original filename minus its extension, which is given by `${file%.*}`. Then `${base#A}` removes its leading `A` character, leaving just the digits, which we then print to a new filename using the desired format.

Answer (score 5):

Using Perl's rename utility:

```
prename 's/(\d+)\./sprintf "%04d.", $1/e' A*.txt
```

`prename` is sometimes available under the name `rename`.  There is, however, another unrelated and incompatible utility called `rename` that is installed by default on some distributions.

Debian-like distributions, among others, have Perl's rename/prename installed by default.  If your distribution does not, instructions for installing it can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148380/53604)

(Hat tip to Steeldriver for improved version of the command.)

#### Example

Consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
A12345.txt  A123.txt  A12.txt  A1.txt
```

Now, let's run prename:

```
$ prename 's/(\d+)\./sprintf "%04d.", $1/e' A*.txt
$ ls
A0001.txt  A0012.txt  A0123.txt  A12345.txt
```

#### How it works

A single substitute command is used:

```
s/(\d+)\./sprintf "%04d.", $1/e
```

- `(\d+)\.` matches one or more digits followed by a period.  The digits are saved in group 1.
- The final `e` tells perl to evaluate the command `sprintf "%04d.", $1`. This command returns the digits of group 1 in format `%04d` meaning zero-filled four digits, followed by a period.

Comment: @steeldriver Your `sprintf` suggestion is superior.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I do "man prename", there is a manual page. But when I run "rename 's/(\d+)\./sprintf "%04d.", $1/e' A*.txt", it says "command not found". I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Christin Curious.  Try `type prename` and `type rename`.  Also, what distribution/OS are you on?

Comment: It says ' Command not found' for both prename and rename.  I have a macintosh. Sorry I don't know what distribution means.

Comment: Christin: Hmm, that is not good.  One option, according to [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/152627/renaming-many-files-in-mac-os-x-batch-processing), is to install rename via homebrew with: `brew install rename`.  Another option, if you already have perl installed (I don't know what the default is on OSX), is to download the script ( `wget 'http://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=displaycode;node_id=303814' -O rename` ) and then install it on your path.  If you are going to do a lot renaming, then `rename` does make things simpler.  If not, then @steeldriver's solution is good.