# Remove a specific suffix from all the files in a directory

Tags: files, rename

I have a genotype file which I have split it into more than 2000 5K SNPs files by using

```
split -d geno_file
```

the output that I get is something like this:

```
table_subset_0001
table_subset_0002
table_subset_0003
.
.
table_subset_0099
.
.
table_subset_0999
```

I want to delete 0 and get

```
table_subset_1
table_subset_2
table_subset_3
.
.
table_subset_93
.
.
table_subset_999
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: why do you want that?  the leading zeroes are there so that the filenames sort properly without need for extra tools, so they can be unsplit or concatenated easily later (e.g. with just `cat`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on to @John1024's solution, here's a similar one that uses standard Bash commands:

```
for file in table_subset_*; do
    new_name=$(echo "$file" | sed -E -e 's/_0+/_/')
    mv "$file" "$new_name"
done
```

The principle is the same. We iterate over all files and replace the `_0` with `_`.

Comment: ... or with bash extended globs, `mv "$file" "${file/_+(0)/_/}"` maybe (avoiding the need for `sed`)?

Comment: @steeldriver Good suggestion, I don't know the bash parameter expansions by heart unfortunately ^^. I will keep my solution, since it already works as it is, but feel free to answer with yours as well. It's definitely more elegant.

Comment: Done here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384407/203203

Comment: To make it _standard_, you'd need to change the `sed` command to `sed 's/_0\{1,\}/_/'` or `sed 's/_00*/_/'`

Answer (score 3):

Using the Perl `rename` utility:

```
rename 's/_0+/_/' table_subset_*
```

This replaces `_` followed by one or more zero characters with just `_`.

The above works with the `rename` utility, sometimes called `prename`, that comes with Perl.  Some distributions install the `rename` utility from `util-linux` utility which is completely incompatible.

If Perl's rename is not already installed on your system, methods for installing it may be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148379/delete-spaces-hyphens-and-underscores-in-filenames/148380#148380)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of purity...

A pure `bash` answer: (thanks @steeldriver)

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in table_subset_0*; do
    mv "$file" "${file/_+(0)/_}"
done
```

A pure GNU `sed` answer:

```
ls | sed -n -r '
    /^(table_subset_)0+(.*)/ ! d
    s//mv & \1\2/
    e
'
```

A pure GNU `awk` answer:

```
ls | awk -F '_0+' 'NF > 1 { system("mv " $0 " " $1 "_" $2) }'
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one liner would be(run from within the folder in question):

```
rename 's/(?<=table_subset_)([0])+//' ./*
```

But if run from outside:

```
rename 's/(?<=table_subset_)([0])+//' /path/to/files/folder/*
```

Comment: Apparently, the OP wants her files to be renamed.

Comment: Oh, missed that! Let me fix that

Comment: I don't know rename but isn't that supposed to remove any sequence of zeros? table_subset_1000 would be renamed to table_subset_1, right?

Comment: Yes that would be right.

Comment: @xhienne I believe this is better?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` at first instead of going with `split` and performing another `rename` tool.

```
awk 'NR%5000==1{ file=sprintf("table_subset_%d", ((++c)) )} {print >file}' geno_file
```

this will split the `geno_file` file into the blocks of 5K files with numeric suffix without leading zeros, but you are feel free to use `0Xd` in. above with 4 digits of length like `sprintf("..._%04d", ((++c)) )`

Or if you would like to split your `geno_file` to only 9 parts of output file, so at first with `split` and right using of its options to set start the numeric suffix from 1 (default is 0) and `-a N` (generate suffixes of length N (default 2)), you could simply use as follows:

```
split -a 1 --numeric-suffixes=1 -l TOTALLINES/9HERE table_subset_
```

But still don't forget `awk` solution.